# Use factory pattern with single and multiple returns

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

I have a factory pattern implemented for handling several messages which derive from the class MessageBase (e.g. StartMessage, etc).

To handle these messages, I have different handlers that derive from IMessageHandler:

```
public interface IMessageHandler
{
      MessageHandleResult HandleMessage(MessageBase message);
}

public class StartMessageHandler: IMessageHandler
{
      public MessageHandleResult IMessageHandler.HandleMessage(MessageBase message)
      {
         ...
      }
}
```

To retrieve the handlers, it is quite simple:

```
var messagehandler = MessageHandlerFactory.GetMessageHandlerFor(message);
var result = messagehandler.HandleMessage(message);
```

But in the new situation, I have to handle a new type of message (which also neatly derives from MessageBase). The messagehandler for this new message must return the result as a list of messageresults:

```
public class NewMessageHandler: IMessageHandler
{
      public List<MessageHandleResult> IMessageHandler.HandleMessage(MessageBase message)
      {
         ...
      }
}
```

Any ideas on how to refactor this in a correct way. The solution was working perfectly for 6 types of messages until this new message type was introduced.

Comment: What about having `MessageHandleResult<T>` where Result is type of `T`. In that case, every implementation of `IMessageHandler<T>` can define the return type of `HandleMessage`.

Comment: Or return an `IEnumerable<MessageResult>`, and if only one result then return `new MessageResult[] { result }`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The main issue is I have 6 handlers that will always return a single result and the new 7th handler must return multiple results. Return IEnumerable is a solution, but it is weird to force the existing 6 handlers to return an Array when they always return 1 result.

Answer (score 0):

Change the interface to:

```
public interface IMessageHandler
{
      IEnumerable<MessageHandleResult> HandleMessage(MessageBase message);
}
```

This would enable you to dispense with the `MessageHandlerFactory.GetMessageHandlerFor` step, which is a design smell anyway.

Instead, you can simply pass a message to a list of message handlers and concatenate the results:

```
var results = messagehandlers.SelectMany(h => h.HandleMessage(message));
```

Message handlers that don't handle a particular subtype of `MessageBase` can return an empty list.